# Undefined is not an object(evaluating 'a.PropTypes.string') in ReactNative while building an android and ios app

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-proptypes

There are many similar kinds of questions are available there, But mine is still different because the most of the questions have given the solution like use:

`import PropTypes from 'prop-types';`

as a separate package and not from:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
```

Which I am already doing since I have started my project. Still,I am facing the same issue.
Below is one of the place in my code where I am using proptypes:

```
ListItem.propTypes = {
  imageUrl: PropTypes.number,
  itemTitle: PropTypes.string,
  careerText: PropTypes.string,
  distanceText: PropTypes.number,
  imageWidth: PropTypes.number,
  imageHeight: PropTypes.number,
  onPressButton: PropTypes.func,
  isSpecial: PropTypes.bool,
};
```

- Note: My application was using expo before but now I have removed it and all the dependencies*

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: is `prop-types` present in your `node_modules` folder?

Comment: yes it is there

Comment: Can you create a example code on expo.io and share it?

Comment: But i am not using expo @SandipNirmal

Comment: Okay, I’ll try to create component with similar props.

Comment: What version of ``react`` and ``react-native`` you are using.

Comment: react-native: 0.50.3 and react : 16.0.0

Comment: I was facing some problem using react-native version 0.50. You can try upgrading react and react-native.

Comment: thanks @SandipNirmal I upgrade it to 0.55.4 and it worked for me. You can post this solution as an answer and I will mark it as right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing some problem using react-native version 0.50. You can try upgrading react and react-native versions. I think this should fix the problem for you.